# How to use conditional volatility under GARCH model to forecast price?

Tags: garch

I have come across videos on youtube about GARCH model in stimulating and forecasting stock price, however, it is programmed in R language. Is there any tutorials teach the similar as the videos shown below, but programmed in python?

(Aim: using conditional volatility under GARCH model to stimulate stock price.)

Thanks in advance.

https://m.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL34t5iLfZdduGEuSXYrleeBdvfQcak0Ov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Be aware that GARCH models are used to model the conditional volatility of asset returns, and in this sense, it has nothing to do with implied volatility (eg. see the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_conditional_heteroskedasticity)).*

---

#### Python package & example for GARCH modeling:

**Within the `Python` framework you can find the well-known `arch` package developed  by [Kevin Sheppard](https://www.kevinsheppard.com/)**. The package have many different ARCH & GARCH models, which can be viewed in this [list](https://arch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/univariate/volatility.html#volatility-processes). The author also include ways of [simulating](https://arch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/univariate/univariate_volatility_modeling.html?highlight=simulation#Simulation) and [forecasting](https://arch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/univariate/forecasting.html) asset returns from the models, which is helpful in your scenario. If you [read the documentation](https://arch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) you will see that he has provided an abundance of examples, that will help you implement and understand how the package works.

**If you want to implement a GARCH model from scratch in `Python`,** then you can follow [his example](https://www.kevinsheppard.com/teaching/python/notes/notebooks/example-gjr-garch/) of implementing and estimating a GJR-GARCH(1,1) model. In this example, he also teaches you how to find the standard errors using the sandwich covariance estimator.

Alternatively, there's a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=96nSIMS9_Y0&t), that shows you how to simulate (from scratch) a GARCH(2,2) model and furthermore how to estimate & forecast the model using the `arch` package.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. And thanks for your help.